# Weekly scheduler with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to build a weekly scheduler in javascript allowing functions to run only on specific time ranges and days of week ranges.

There will be two full input dates. "From" and "To". And I need to check if "now" is inside of the two dates time and day-of-week range.

I've looked through the docs for both moment.js and these two plugins:

https://github.com/gf3/moment-range

https://github.com/icambron/twix.js

I did not find any clear solution in these frameworks, but I'm amazed that it doesn't seem to exist seeing as the frameworks seems so complete. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Is moment.js the right tool for my weekly scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/gf3/moment-range docs.

Find out if your moment falls within a date range:

```
var start = new Date(2012, 4, 1);
var end   = new Date(2012, 4, 23);
var when  = moment("2012-05-10", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var range = moment().range(start, end);

when.within(range); // true
```

**Updated:**

This will check to see if the day of the week is within range.

```
function checkDay(range, when) {
    var isWithin = false;
    range.by('days', function(moment){
        if(when.within(range) && moment.day() === when.day) isWithin = true;
    });
    return isWithin;
}

console.log( checkDay(range, when) );
```

**Updated Again:**

Based on your feedback, I think this should do the trick:

```
var startDate = new Date(2012, 4, 1);
var endDate = new Date(2012, 4, 23);
var dateRange = moment().range(startDate, endDate);

var days = [1,2,3,4,5]; // mon-fri
var startTime = moment('09:00 +0000', 'HH:mm Z'); // 9:00 am UTC
var endTime = moment('17:00 +0000', 'HH:mm Z'); // 5:00 pm UTC
var timeRange = moment().range(startTime, endTime);

function isWithin(dateRange, timeRange, days, when) {
    return (when.within(dateRange) && !!~days.indexOf(when.day()) && moment(when.format('HH:mm Z'), 'HH:mm Z').within(timeRange));
}

var when = moment('2012-05-22 12:32 +0000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z');

console.log(isWithin(dateRange, timeRange, days, when));
```

I'm sure it could you some clean up but I think it should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: This checks it the DATE is within a DATE range. I need to check if the DAY OF WEEK is within the "weekly range". This means that if the date is from 2012-1-15 10:00 to 2012-1-16 22:00 and those dates are Monday and Tuesday (lets say). It should return true EVERY Monday and Tuesday within that time range.

Comment: Getting closer I think. But this doesn't check if the time is within range, only the day of week? What I need is like a "open hours schedule", so the times are as important as the day of week.